# Using iptables --ctstate NEW with custom chains

Tags: iptables

I have a question regarding an iptables example at https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2018/06/21/how-to-create-iptables-firewall-using-custom-chains

Is the rule

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -j chain-outgoing-services
```

correct, or as it is a new connection, should connection tracking be used as follows?

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j chain-outgoing-services
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule in the article:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -j chain-outgoing-services
```

is the correct rule. As all outgoing packets need to traverse that chain, not just the `NEW`.

Comment: So, if a new connection is made, the response is tracked by the inbound ESTABLISHED,RELATED rule?

Comment: Yes............